# How to use regExp in Word VBA code to find a keyword in a word document?

Tags: excel, regex, vba, ms-word

I'm triying to use this regExp pattern `^SFT(-[A-Z]+){2,3}(-\d+)$` to find a key word in a Word document with VBA Excel but it doesn't work and I get a 5625 error due to special caracter.

Anybody knows how to solve out this?

Examples of data I'm triying to find:

```
SFT-LTE-SEC-8, SFT-LTE-ROLES-PMR-1, SFT-LTE-MCPTT-2
```

```
Sub FulfilMatrix()
    Dim oFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim strPath, headerAndDocument As String
    Dim wordRange As Word.Range
    Dim BoolFound As Boolean
    Dim wordPage As Integer
    strPath = "C:\Users\Requirements\LLD LTE.docx"
    Set oFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If oFSO.FileExists(strPath) Then
        Set wordApp = New Word.Application
        wordApp.Visible = True
        With wordApp
            'It hides markup when opening
            .Options.ShowMarkupOpenSave = False
            'file is opened
            Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(strPath)
        End With
    End If
    
    Do
        With wordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
            wordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "^SFT(-[A-Z]+){2,3}(-\d+)$" ' requirements pattern
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            '.Execute
            BoolFound = .Found
        End With
    
        If BoolFound Then
            ' capture du numéro de page du HLD où se trouve la SFT
            wordPage = wordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            debug.print wordpage
         end if 
    Loop While BoolFound
    
    
    'to quit the entire Application:
    wordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    'screenUpdating on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Set objWApp = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordRange = Nothing
    Set wordParagraph = Nothing
    
    EndTime = Timer '
    Debug.Print EndTime - StartTime;
    If EndTime - StartTime Mod (60) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print EndTime - StartTime;
    Else
        Debug.Print ((EndTime - StartTime) \ 60)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show the code you have tried.  [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Also include example data of what you try to find with this pattern. And include the full error message you get and in which line of the code you get it. Also see [mcve].

Comment: Note that `Find` in Word does accept some wildcards (see http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm) but it does not support regular expressions. So `.Text = "^SFT(-[A-Z]+){2,3}(-\d+)$"` does not accept a regular expression pattern but you can use wildcards.

Comment: So you try to find everything that starts with `SFT-LTE-`? Then you can just search for `SFT-LTE-*`. If that is not correct then your data example doesn't represent your data properly. Can you explain which parts of the data are fixed? And which are variable? Maybe it can be built a "pattern" with just using wildcards. But that's impossible without good data representation or you explaining the pattern of the data.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous errors in your code so I have added comments to show where they are and how to fix them.

You will still need to fix the wildcards as there isn't enough data in your question to identify your exact requirements. You can find details on using wildcards at the Word MVP site: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

```
Sub FulfilMatrix()
    Dim oFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    'each variable in the line must have a datatype
    Dim strPath As String, headerAndDocument As String
    Dim wordRange As Word.Range
    'Dim BoolFound As Boolean  - not needed
    Dim wordPage As Integer
    strPath = "C:\Users\Requirements\LLD LTE.docx"
    Set oFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If oFSO.FileExists(strPath) Then
        Set wordApp = New Word.Application
        wordApp.Visible = True
        With wordApp
            'It hides markup when opening
            .Options.ShowMarkupOpenSave = False
            'file is opened
            Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(strPath)
        End With
    End If
    
    'This do loop is in the wrong place. You need to loop the execution of the Find
    '    Do
    'don't use Selection with VBA work with objects directly
    'With wordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
    Set wordRange = wordDoc.Content
    With wordRange
        With .Find
            'not needed if working with objects directly
            'wordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "^SFT(-[A-Z]+){2,3}(-\d+)$" ' requirements pattern
            .Forward = True
            'need to stop execution at end of document
            '.Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            'if you use wildcards in .Text, Find needs to know that they are not literal characters
            '.MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            '.Execute
            'Unless the find is executed Found will evaluate to false
            'BoolFound = .Found
        End With
        'Loop the exectution, not the result
        'If BoolFound Then
        Do While .Find.Execute()
            'Find redefines wordRange to the range of the match
            ' capture du numéro de page du HLD où se trouve la SFT
            wordPage = .Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            Debug.Print wordPage
            'need to collapse the range so that Find continues after the match
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            '         End If
            '    Loop While BoolFound
        Loop
    End With
    'to quit the entire Application:
    wordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    'screenUpdating on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
    'Set objWApp = Nothing - you don't have a variable named objWApp
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordRange = Nothing
    Set wordParagraph = Nothing
    
    EndTime = Timer '
    Debug.Print EndTime - StartTime;
    If EndTime - StartTime Mod (60) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print EndTime - StartTime;
    Else
        Debug.Print ((EndTime - StartTime) \ 60)
    End If
End Sub
```